# Getting Error: Cannot find module 'html' in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, web-deployment

I have deployed my full-stack web app on Heroku after following some blogs on structures which should be followed by the MERN app before deploying it on Heroku. I did the same thing but still, I am getting `error` in `logs`.

Error:

```
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193856+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193883+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193884+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193885+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193885+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193885+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/index.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193886+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193886+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193887+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193889+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193889+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193890+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193890+00:00 app[web.1]: at new View (/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193891+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:587:12)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193891+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193891+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/controllers/homeController.js:15:6
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193891+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/middlewares/bigPromise.js:4:19
2022-07-07T13:23:00.193892+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2022-07-07T13:23:00.194187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=project-review-webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=26bf0adc-0ece-413c-81e3-62b84376c188 fwd="103.67.17.76" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=510 protocol=https
```

Blogs I followed :

[Deploying MERN App to Heroku](https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-app-to-heroku/)

[How to Deploy a MERN Application to Heroku](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploying-a-mern-application-using-mongodb-atlas-to-heroku/)

Procfile:
`web: node server.js`

Structure of my app directory:

```
 - client
 - config
 - controllers
 - middlewares
 - models
 - node_modules
 - routes
 - utils
 - .env
 - .gitignore
 - app.js
 - nodemon.json
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
 - Procfile
 - server.js
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectreview",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": " nodemon server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18"
  }
}
```

I don't why I am getting this error? And, How can I solve it? What I have done wrong here?

Comment: Is your code public on GitHub that I could take a look at to help?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/Harsh2110mishra/projectReviewWebApp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the code in `controllers/homeController.js`:

```js
exports.home = BigPromise((req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .render(
      "../client/public/index.html"
    );
});
```

### Why you're seeing this error

Here, you're asking Express to "render" your `index.html` file, which means you want Express to use a [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html%22) to process and transform the file. Because you specified the file extension (`html`), Express will try to load an NPM module called `html` as the template engine to process the file. The error you're seeing is from Express trying to load that `html` NPM module, but it's not installed. However, none of this is what you really want.

### How to fix it

What you actually want Express to do is just send the HTML file unmodified to the client, not to process the file with a template engine. For that, use [`sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) instead of `render`, like this:

```js
const path = require("path");

exports.home = BigPromise((req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "../client/public/index.html")
    );
});
```

Note that your `client` directory in your GitHub repo is currently empty, so you'll also need to add the file `client/public/index.html` in order for this to work.

And all this can be debugged and tested locally, without Heroku involved. You can run `npm run dev` on your local system and point a web browser at `http://localhost:4000` to see the results.